# Neo4j with Tomcat JVM configuration in production

Tags: tomcat, neo4j

I wanted to know how best should be the configuration of the JVM when I'm using **Neo4j** with **Tomcat** in an embedded mode on let's say a 8GB RAM size.

Comment: Hard to say without context, esp. how much your app will take. But probably 2G heap for neo 2G memory mapping 2G for your app?

Comment: Thanks.
It's a kind of microblogging plateform which would contain (with this hardware configuration) around million nodes and 10 millions relationships

Comment: Then it should be fine, just make sure to write sensible queries, have indexes in place.

Comment: Thanks :)
And maybe a stupid question, where should I configure the JVM to book for neo? For the app it should be in the tomcat scripts, but can't find where should I modify for neo

Comment: in `/path/to/neo/conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`

Comment: Isn't neo4j-wrapper.conf only used for the server mode? I'm using the embedded mode